# Two questions about meaning of "settle" and "home"

Tags: word-meaning

> Now that you have officially arrived in Canada, it's time to **settle** into your new **home**.

1. Does the word **home** refer to flat and apartments or new envirenment in a new country?
2. I have always had difficulty understanding of meaning **settle into** . Could you help me with its meaning in simple English?

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, the word "home" refers to both "flat and apartments" and "new environment in a new country".

In this context, the emphasis is on "new environment in a new country".  The Canadians are inviting you to think of Canada as your home; they hope you will choose to think of yourself as a Canadian.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/home) is an excellent set of examples of the many usages of the word home.  As for "settle in", it has the meaning of "get used to".  For example, one may also settle into a new job or new routine or even a theater seat.

Answer (score 0):

*home* generally refers to the *structure and land* where you live. It could be a house, apartment, etc. but we still call them a home.

Related to environment, you can say *home country*, *hometown* etc.

*settle in* refers to the process of moving in to a new location/place, including physically moving yourself, your furniture, etc. and becoming familiar with the area (stores, schools, services, etc.).
You were moving and now you are *settled*.

Comment: I'd argue that in the given example, Canada itself is the home, rather than a physical structure.